# This Xaml is not valid... I don't understand why

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I've a strange problem with xaml.
Visual studio for wp tell me that the xaml is not valid but when I execute the app it works fine.

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Friends_And_Money.ContList"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Friends_And_Money"    
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot è la griglia radice in cui viene inserito tutto il contenuto della pagina-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:ContactPictureConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate">
            <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Width="62" 
         Height="62" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
        <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="AddrBookJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
            <Setter Property="GridCellSize"  Value="113,113"/>
            <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="Grid" />
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" Width="113" Height="113" Margin="6" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="48" Padding="6" 
                             Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>



        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">         
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" ></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" ></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Photo, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Width="62" Height="62" Stretch="Fill" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Light"  FontSize="40" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>



    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">


        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contiene il nome dell'applicazione e il titolo della pagina-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ContactTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - inserire ulteriore contenuto qui-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LongList" 
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}"
                                    JumpListStyle="{StaticResource AddrBookJumpListStyle}"
                                    LayoutMode="List"
                                    IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                                    HideEmptyGroups ="true" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>   
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

I've followed the tutorial (with the difference of a longlistselector) from here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286418(v=vs.105).aspx][1]

How I say all works fine, longlistselector show me images and contact's name.

Struct to show:

```
namespace Friends_And_Money
{
    class ContactStruct 
    {
       public string FirstName
       {
          get;
          set;
       }

       public WriteableBitmap Photo
       {
          get;
          set;
       }

       public ContactStruct(string name, WriteableBitmap photo)
       {
          this.FirstName = name;
          this.Photo = photo;
       }

    }
}
```

Thanks to every one that help.

New details: 
The error is signed in datatemplate AddrBookItemTemplate and I've noted that if I leave image source attribute the error disappear.
So seems be something with the binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Visual studio for wp tell me that the xaml is not valid but when I execute the app it works fine.

Please ignore the designer. It's rather moody.

Comment: For first, thanks for your reply.
Is my first approach with wp and it started with this strange way. There's no risk that they refuse my app for this "xaml not valid" message?

Comment: The designer doesn't reflect reality at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe a bad copy / paste, but your first element (`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>`) is not close.